# Slow MySQL restore after mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysqldumpslow

I did mysqldump and when I try to restore it:

```
mysql -u root -pmypassword dbname < dump.sql
```

it says:

> mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure

and takes pause about 10 sec, even if `dump.sql` is very small. It's no problem about message, but how to get rid of pause?

Comment: Are you sure the "pause" you are noticing is related to the message?

Comment: I think this message does not affect the "pause" because when I type: mysql -u root -p dbname < dump.sql, and then type password it also takes pause